# Error with Trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger with mysql but it gives me several error. The last one has no description (MySQL says only Error!) and so i'm here to ask for your help

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER SellStockTrigger
AFTER INSERT ON UtenteHaAzione
FOR EACH ROW



BEGIN
DECLARE BUD DOUBLE;
DECLARE SOMMA DOUBLE;
SET BUD=(SELECT BUDGET
FROM UTENTE 
WHERE CODUTENTE = NEW.CODUTENTE);

SET SOMMA= NEW.COSTOAZIONE*NEW.QTAAZIONE;
SET BUD=BUD-SOMMA;
IF (BUD<0) 
 raise_application_error (6002, 'budget exceeded');
ELSE
UPDATE UTENTE
WHERE CODUTENTE=NEW.CODUTENTE
SET BUDGET=BUD; 
END IF;
END;
delimiter ;
```

This is my database structure. 
[Utente_Table](http://bancapp.altervista.org/Utente.PNG)
[UtenteHaAzione_Table](http://bancapp.altervista.org/UtenteHaAzione.PNG)

Unfortunately i used to write trigger in Oracle Databases, so i'm sure that i'm missing something!
Thanks for your help

Comment: first thing first change `END;` to `END; |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things -

First after the end you need the delim something as

```
END; |
delimiter ;
```

Next the update query is wrong and should be as

```
UPDATE UTENTE
SET BUDGET=BUD
WHERE CODUTENTE=NEW.CODUTENTE
;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still have an error for "raise_application_error (6002, 'budget exceeded');". What is MySQL syntax for this oracle expression?

Comment: hmm are you sure that the BUD is +ve value ? you can create a test table and insert the value of BUD from trigger to see what value its getting.

Comment: i think that the problem is the method raise_application_error...like if it does not exists in MySQL syntax...

Comment: yes raise_aplication_error is not there in mysql but in mysql you can use signal http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html#signal-condition-information-items